# doc.createTreeWalker is not a function

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress

When I click the button with text 'Create' the text is replaced to 'Confirm?'
This is the HTML:

[image]

and the pageObject:

```
create() {
        return cy.get('im-page.hydrated', { includeShadowDom: true })
            .find('im-button', { includeShadowDom: true })
            .eq(1)
            .find('button', { includeShadowDom: true })
            .click({ force: true })
    }
```

```
confirmBtn() {
        return cy.get('im-page.hydrated').find('im-button')
            .eq(1)
            .find('button.success.outline')
            .contains('Confirm?')
        
            
    }
```

Then when Cypress click on Confirm I got this error:

[image]

Comment: The call to `createTreeWalker` is related to `includeShadowDom` option, but you don't show it being used for `confirmBtn`. Is that an omission in above snippet, or have you left it out in the actual test? Or is shadowDom turned on globally?

Comment: @Fody I also used ``includeShadowDom```, it is just left out on this snippet, but it does not work

Comment: That's ok, I was just following the Cypress source code and wanted to verify was looking at the right part.

Comment: The Confirm button is clicked, then the error is triggered

Comment: It may be a timing problem, could you try `.find('button.success.outline:contains(Confirm))`

Comment: @Fody have tried your suggestion but I got the same error

Comment: Ok, so it's not a timing issue.

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue logged [doc.createTreeWalker is not a function #20813](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/20813) but not yet resolved.

From the source code the `doc` part refers to the previous subject, i.e the element before the `.find()` which above is `cy.get('im-page.hydrated').find('im-button').eq(1)`.

My guess is because the button changes on the Create click, something in that previous subject becomes invalid when you try to access the Confirm button.

A couple of ideas to try (just guesses at this stage)

```js
// using jquery to avoid the treeWalker (used by the .find() command)

cy.get('im-page.hydrated im-button:eq(1) button.success.outline:contains(Confirm)')
```

```js
// using an alias and "withinSubject" option to explicitly define `doc`

cy.get('im-page.hydrated im-button:eq(1)`).as('parent')

cy.get('@parent').then($parent => {
  cy.get('button.success.outline:contains(Confirm)', { withinSubject: $parent })
```

You should turn on shadowDOM globally to avoid missing any parts that need it.

```js
// cypress.json

{
  ...
  "includeShadowDom": true
}
```

---

**#3** - just do a simple search for "Confirm", since likely only one thing at a time needs confirming.

```js
cy.contains('button.success.outline', 'Confirm')
```

Comment: #1 didnt found ```cy.get('im-page.hydrated im-button:eq(1) button.success.outline:contains(Confirm)') ```                                                                                                     #2 Cypress times out finding 
```im-page.hydrated im-button:eq(1)```
 ShadowDom was already turned on cypress.json                                                                #3  ```cy.contains('button.success.outline', 'Confirm')```
cypress first  clicks the button then continues searching for the button